# Avocado hard and grey inside

Tags: fruit, avocados, ripe

I had a batch of avocados from the supermarket, as I normally do.

I often have 3-5 days before they're past the point of being edible.

This batch was not more that 2 days old, and three out of five looked like the avocado below (this is probably the best of the bad bunch), *despite being firm*.

[image: avocado, cut in half with stone showing. It has grey zones that circle the avocado]

In fact I felt like I was being a little cheeky and risking opening an unripe avocado.

Is the greyness from damage or disease?

I tasted one, and rather that tasting over or under ripe it was just bland.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, avocados with this behavior are normally picked too early. Although all avocados are picked early in commercial settings because of transit to market timing, when they are picked TOO early they begin to mature as "seeds" before they actually ripen. The flesh becomes fiberous, rather than soft, as the seed prepares to germinate. Alas, I've never been able to tell if this will happen before buying them.